# Decode unicode ASP

Tags: asp-classic

How i can decode an unicode string with ASP?
I have an String like this :

```
> Sweet Dreams
> &#9734;:*&acute;&uml;`*:&#9734;
```

and i want write decoded string in a json

Answer (score 0):

ASP does not have a HTMLDecode function, so you will need to use a third party function to decode:

ASP can run JScript, which means you can take a JavaScript function such as the one below and add the following to the top:

```
<script language="JScript" runat="server">
```

and add this at the bottom:

```
</script>
```

Save it as something like encoder.asp, now you can include this and use the functions of it:

```
Dim encodedString, decodedString
encodedString = "Sweet Dreams &#9734;:*&acute;&uml;`*:&#9734;"
decodedString = Encoder.htmlDecode(encodedString)
```

http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode

Comment: I have to write in a json...i need an asp function

Comment: This is ASP, ASP can be run in VBScript or JScript and you can switch languages.

Answer (score -1):

print/echo to screen and let the browser do it: ☆:*´¨`*:☆